# JavaScript to trigger events based on which div takes up most of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events, visibility

Basically I have a list of divs like this:

`<div id="1">`First div`</div>`

`<div id="2">`Second div`</div>`

and I want the most visible div to affect what is displayed in a different constant div, like this:

`<div id="link">`First div's link`</div>` (If the first div took up most of the page)

And then

`<div id="link">`Second div's link`</div>` (If the second div is scrolled to)

How would I get the Javascript to figure out which div is being viewed (calculated by which is taking up the greatest % of pixel space on the screen) and then trigger an event for the 'link' div based on that?

Answer (score 0):

EDITING MY PREVIOUS ANSWER.

You have to find out how far each div is from the top of the document (it's a fixed number, regardless of how far the window is scrolled down):

`divTop = $('#1').offset().top`

Then, find out how far the window is scrolled:

`scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop()`

You also need the window's height (which is the height of visible portion of the document):

`windowHeight = $(window).height()`

And, you need the height of each div:

`divHeight = $('#1').height()`.

Then you calculate where each div starts **relative to the top of the window**, which could be a negative number -- if the window is scrolled down past the top of the div -- in which case you make it zero, using Math.max:

`divTopInWindow = Math.max(0, divTop - scrollTop)`

Similarly, you calculate the div's bottom, relative to the top of the window. If the div extends past the bottom of the window, you make it the window's height:

`divBottomInWindow = Math.min(windowHeight, divTop + divHeight - scrollTop)`

Finally, you figure out the percent visible of each div like so (actually it's the fraction, not the percent, but whatever):

`percentVisible = (divBottomInWindow - divTopInWindow) / windowHeight`

I haven't tried it, so there may be a mistake in there, but it's definitely the right approach.

-------------------------- OLD ANSWER BELOW JUST FOR REFERENCE ------------------
I don't think you're using the expression "trigger an event" properly. Sounds like you just want to set the content of a div based on some condition (i.e. whether div 1 is taller than div 2).

Assuming you have jQuery or Zepto loaded on the page:

```
if( $('#1').height() > $('#2').height() ) {
    $('#link').html('First div link');
}
else {
    $('#link').html('Second div link');
}
```

Comment: Not quite.. the divs are all different sizes (there are approx 30 of them) so it's more about which is on screen vs which is actually higher. Thanks for trying though.